# Batch value insert in Redis list

Tags: python, redis

Is there a way to store multiple values in a Redis list at the same time?  I can only find a way to insert 1 value at the time in a list.

I've been looking at the following commands documentation: http://redis.io/commands

**update:** I have created a [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=598) for this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it doesn't look like that's possible. You might be able to use MULTI (transactions) to store multiple values in an atomic sequence.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a pipeline, if using redis-py you could check out the below, I ran this on an aws instance of redis elasticache and found the following:

```
import redis
rs = redis.StrictRedis(host='host', port=6379, db=0)
q='test_queue'
```

Ran in 0.17s for 10,000 vals

```
def multi_push(q,vals):
    pipe = rs.pipeline()
    for val in vals:
        pipe.lpush(q,val)
    pipe.execute()
```

Ran in 13.20s for 10,000 vals

```
def seq_push(q,vals):
    for val in vals:
        rs.lpush(q,val)
```

~ 78x faster.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for relevance in 2020, at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can if you run 2.4. While it isn't marked stable yet, it should be soon IIRC. that said I'm running out of trunk and it's been rock solid for me with many gigs of data and a high rate if churn. For more details on variadic commands see [2.4 and other news](http://antirez.com/post/2-4-and-other-news.html).

Answer (score 1):

For lists, not that i am aware of, but depending on your data volume, it might be efficient for you to re-cast your data to use redis' multiset command, HMSET, which does indeed give you multiple inserts in a single call:

```
HMSET V3620 UnixTime 1309312200 UID 64002 username "doug" level "noob"
```

As you expect, HMSET creates the redis keyed to V3620. The *key* follows the HMSET command followed by multiple field--value pairs:

```
HMSET key field 1 value 1 field 2 value 2
```